# I need help combining a string and a variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hi i am working on using New-Item with the option -Path, in the path I want the string of the path and then a variable that the end of that path

I have tried `"\\path\S_."Variable""`

This is what I have so far

```
New-Item -Path "\\servername\Share" -Name $_."samAccountName" -ItemType "directory" -Force
```

what i want is the variable to be included in the path after share.

What I tried above has not worked so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To to this, it's as simple as:

```
"\\servername\$variable"
```

or

```
$variable = "\\servername\" + $variable
```

Answer (score 2):

To use dot-noted Variables in parameters use them in brackets (the samAccountName too):

```
New-Item -Path "\\servername\Share_$($_.variable)" -Name ($_.samAccountName) -ItemType "directory" -Force
```

another way is to build your string with the format operator `-f`:

```
New-Item -Path ("\\servername\Share{0}" -f ($_.var) ) -Name ($_."samAccountName") -ItemType "directory" -Force
```

`{0}` is replaced by the expression at position 0 behind the `-f` so you could build a string with multiple expressions>

```
"{0} , {1} , {2}" -f ($_.var),($var + 3),(get-date)
```

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to create paths is by using the [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet.

```
$newFolder = Join-Path -Path '\\Servername\Share' -ChildPath ($_.SamAccountName)
New-Item -Path $newFolder -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
```

<sup>Note: I ended the command with `| Out-Null` to avoid console output</sup>